# Fabrik Calc Element to display selected options of multipledropdown

Tags: php, ajax, joomla

I am developing a joomla site using the fabrik component.

I have a cascading drop-down (rendered as multiple drop-down) inside a form.
I need to create a calculation element that uses Ajax to display the options that user selected from the multiple drop-down.

I tried using the code from fabrik [wiki site](http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?wiki/calculation-element/) but it is not working.

Thank you

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at joomla.stackexchange.com).